# When I use VIM via terminal, I keep getting duplicate files with a ~ appended to the end. What are these?

Tags: python, bash, unix, vim, terminal

For example, I'll use VIM to code a Python script and then save the file.

When I navigate to the directory I saved in and use the `ls` command, up comes:

> test_file.py
>   test_file.py~

Are these backup files?

Comment: Yes those are backup files.

Comment: @RohitJain I've never seen such files generated (permanently) by vim.. I guess the file is backup file from gedit or another text editor

Comment: @RohitJain it's quite annoying how cluttered it can become if I don't periodically delete these. Is there a way to disable them? Or have them save to a different directory?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @user can you show your `~/.vimrc` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl my vimrc is completely default (other than four lines added to change the spacing/indents to suit Python specifically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the files that end with the tilde (`~`) are backups of files right before you edited it.

These backups will be handy if you experience a crash.  If you want to save them in another directory, you can add this to your .vimrc:

```
set backupdir=~/vim_tmp,.
set directory=~/vim_tmp,.
```

where `~/vim_tmp` is the directory you want to store your backup files.

Comment: can you show a documentation reference? *my* vim don't create `~` files

Comment: Interesting, I just tested it out and you're right, it's a backup of your last save. Do you know if there is a way to change which directory VIM saves these backups to? It can get really messy if I let them pile up.

Comment: Sure, I just added it to my answer.

Comment: @jh314 Why does my - ubuntu 12.04 - vim 7.2 - don't create such files? (have almost complete default vimrc as well)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are automatic backup files.
I have this in my .vimrc:

```
set writebackup " Write a backup when saving a file...
set nobackup    " ...but delete the backup upon successful completion of the save.
```

Here are the possiblities:

```
'backup' 'writebackup'  action
off      off            no backup made
off      on             backup current file, deleted afterwards (default)
on       off            delete old backup, backup current file
on       on             delete old backup, backup current file
```

I also have
`set backupdir=$VIM/backup`
so that all of my backup files are in the same location, rather than the location of the original file.
See `:help backup` for more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are vim backup files. (if you use default backup file extension)

To disable backup in vim:

```
set nobk
set nowb
```

you may want to check
`:h 'bk'` and `:h 'wb'` for detail.

**@hek2mgl**

if one uses the default backup file name extension, it is tilde `~`. for detail you could check `:h 'bex'`:

```
'backupext' 'bex'   string  (default "~", for VMS: "_")
            global
            {not in Vi}
    String which is appended to a file name to make the name of the
    backup file.
```